# COUNT(*) AS occurrences, php how do i capture the value of each occurance

Tags: php, mysql, count

If i run the following code in phpmyadmin it shows a column with the total occurrences for each friendly_name but when i run it in php and echo out the table i dont know how to pull the value of occurences and add it to my table?

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*) AS occurrences
FROM my_reports 
GROUP BY friendly_name
HAVING count(*) > 1
ORDER BY occurrences DESC
```

This is the code im echoing out and i know its probably incredibly simple but i havent tried this before so i dont know where to start

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sel_rs))
        {
        $hud_id = $row['hud_id'];
        $friendly_name = $row['friendly_name'];     

            echo '<tr><td>'.$hud_id.'</td>';

            echo '<td>'. $friendly_name.'</td>';
            echo '<td>'. what do i put here to show occurances for each.'</td></tr>';
        }

echo "</tbody></table>";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple... `$occurrences = $row['occurrences'];`

PS: You should ditch `mysql_*` functions and learn MySQLi at the very least, or PDO.